# Mocha Chai Testing protected route

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, passport-local

I have an Express server and I'm using passport-local for authentication. I have the following protected route:

```
app.post("/api/test", connect.ensureLoggedIn("/"), (req, res) => {
let test = new Test(req.body);

test
  .save()
  .then(data => {
    return res.json(data);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    return res.status(HTTP_RESPONDE_BAD_REQUEST).send(e);
  });
});
```

I was wondering how can I test the route mentioned above ensuring the user is logged on.

This is my current test (it does not pass, because I wasnt able to send authentication:

```
it("Testing protected route", done => {
 chai
  .request(server)
  .post("/api/test")
  .send(test)
  .end((err, res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

I have tried the following, but when I run the test they redirect me to the login page.

```
it("Testing protected route", done => {
 chai
  .request(server)
  .post("/api/test")
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) // user token id
  .send(test)
  .end((err, res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});

it("Testing protected route", done => {
 chai
  .request(server)
  .post("/api/test")
  .set('token', token) // user token id
  .send(test)
  .end((err, res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

Is there an easier way to test this?

Comment: Your second example is the correct way to do it except that you need to login or otherwise create a valid `token` to use.

Comment: I'm using a valid token. It works fine on Postman

Comment: I'm doing pretty much the exact same thing in my app and it is working fine with a valid token (and assuming you have the correct header as well).

Comment: I dont know what you mean by correct header. Can you show me your code? 

And how did you find your token value?

Comment: I am using `supertest` and a custom HTTP header for the token called `x-access-token` so you will need to adjust for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `supertest` and `mocha` for my unit tests as well as a custom header for the token, but am using a similar pattern for my tests. Before any tests are run the data is loaded into the database and the user is logged in, then that token is used for each of the tests that need authentication.

**TestUtils class**

```
  this.authenticateUser = (user, app) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(app)
      .post('/authenticate')
      .send({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.test_password,
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(res.body.token);
      });
    });
```

**Test Class**

```
describe('Authed Routes', () => {
  let app = null;

  let authUser = null;

  before((done) => {
    // mocking should happen before the app is created.
    app = require('../server');

    // Populate redis data
    TestUtils.populateRedis(() => {
      // Populate db data
      TestUtils.syncAndPopulateDatabase('public-tests', () => {
        // Get the test user
        authUser = TestUtils.getUser();
        // Authenticate the user to get a token
        TestUtils.authenticateUser(authUser, app)
        .then((accessToken) => {
          // Keep the token on the user so we can use it in the tests
          authUser.access_token = accessToken;
          return done();
        })
        .catch((err) => done(err));
      });
    });
  });

  describe('/secure/route', () => {
    it('should allow /secure/route with correct token provided', (done) => {
      request(app)
      .get('/secure/route')
      // add the access token from the user as a header value
      .set('x-access-token', authUser.access_token)
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```